# Layout the GUI with MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am new to MigLayout and I went through Quick-Start provided by them and also watched tutorial on YouTube. I have to layout the following GUI.

[image]

I tried as much as I understood but no success. The elements are not placed properly, like cross get stuck with logo, clouds take squares attached to it and so on. I am getting this (I have changed the cloud image)

[image]

I went through a lot of webpages but still no help. What's the code/method to layout this page only so that I can have a start/understanding? Or what's the code for first two rows of this page? (Take the names of comp as comp1,comp2,etc. or as you like)

My Layout code

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("","[left][fill][fill][fill][fill][fill][right]",""));
add(new JLabel(logo),"span 6"); //the tucan bird
add(cross,"top,align right,wrap"); //the exit cross
add(news,"span,gapleft 800,wrap"); //the label 'news'
add(new JLabel(cloud),"span 3");  //the large cloud picture 

SmallPanel one=new SmallPanel(); //Small Panel are square boxes which I later fill with news
        add(one);

SmallPanel two=new SmallPanel();
    add(two,"wrap");
```

Comment: Where's the code? What issue do you have?

Comment: Yes,its related to programming.I have developed all the necessary modules like news parser,weather module,dictionary but struck in GUI for past 2 hours.Please Help

Comment: I guess I don't understand what sort of help you're looking for.

Comment: I totally messed it up.The cross is not going to rightmost corner.The square blocks are not moving to the right side ,but instead get attached with the cloud

Comment: @admdrew :Please see the EDIT .I am striving for help.

Comment: You might consider posting your current layout code so people can help you improve it. Asking others to do it all for you doesn't usually go over well here.

Comment: @SpacePope:I have posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

A couple notes on MigLayout:

1. The first step for debugging layouts is to add the `debug` flag to your layout constraints (see the [cheat sheet](http://www.miglayout.com/cheatsheet.html):

   ```
   setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "", ""));
   ```

   This will helpfully outline your layout constraints with colored borders so you can see what's where.
2. In my opinion, the column/row constraints on the layout object itself (your series of `[left][fill]...[right]` should be a last resort. I've especially had trouble with the `fill` constraint not doing what I'd expect it to. In your particular case, though, some column constraints might be helpful, which leads me out of the first list portion of my answer and into the second...

The layout you posted in image form above really only has 3 columns:

1. logo and weather icon/text
2. Image column 1 (that includes the "news" label)
3. Image column 2 (with the "close" icon at the top)

Since you want that first column to be wider than the others, I'd suggest something like the following:

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("", "20px[75%]5px[pref]5px[pref]", ""));
```

If you do that, take the `span`s and the `gapleft 800` out of your existing layout; I think the rest of it should still fit. You'll probably also want a `spany` on your `cloud` label/icon - `spany 3` if that label includes the text for the weather; `spany 2` if it doesn't.

The computer I'm on right now isn't set up to test that for you, but hopefully the general advice gets you on the right track. Fiddling with layouts can be one of the more frustrating parts of GUI programming—don't despair, and don't forget that `debug` flag!